# Passive voice of the verb "sell"

Tags: grammar

Does the verb "sell" has a passive voice form? I found this sentence

> The French magazines were sold the most....

Is this correct? Or should I say

> The French magazines sold the most....

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is the idiomatic established expression. The verb "to sell" gains passive meaning in this context, although its grammatical form is active. In fact, this is one of the meanings of the verb, as shown [here](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03yXSpWPO0aUCmdeqFMnPIYOH7NFw%3A1608043884243&ei=bM3YX-SmDrGEhbIPx6uQmAM&q=to%20sell%20meaning&oq=to%20sell%20meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yAggAMgIIADoECAAQR1CaWFiaWGCkeGgAcAN4AIAB8AmIAYMLkgEHMC4xLjctMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjkjIOkntDtAhUxQkEAHccVBDMQ4dUDCA0&uact=5):

[image]

Your first variant is not incorrect, but not so much used.

Comment: Of course, you can also say "This magazine is sold at all good newsagents'" meaning that they have it in stock.

Comment: Yes, quite right!